# xcode-select command not found

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew

I was trying to install homebrew on my mac but failed with the error message saying that xcode-select command not found. I did some searchings online and realized that there is one duplication online. However, it doens't provide me a solution. Below is the information about my environment and settings.

1. I have xcode5.1.1 and xcode6beta6 both installed on the osx mavericks.
2. I checked the PATH variable by "echo $PATH" and the result is "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin".
3. I downloaded the command line tool from the apple download page and installed it.
4. Last, I run the command "ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)" to install the homebrew.

Results I got:

```
 "==> This script will install:
 /usr/local/bin/brew
 /usr/local/Library/...
 /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

 Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
 ==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Library/Caches/Homebrew
 Password:
 ==> Installing the Command Line Tools (expect a GUI popup):
 ==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install
 sudo: /usr/bin/xcode-select: command not found
 Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install
```

"

I have spent a whole day trying to solve the problem. Anyone please help. A lot of thanks.

Comment: The xcode-select tool is installed with Xcode (5 & 6) (command line tools not necessary.). Look in '/usr/bin/' and verify that it's there. If not you need to re-install Xcode.