# Installing Homebrew on Yosemite 10.10.5 error

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, homebrew

I tried to Find an answear with this problem 
but I could so here it is

```
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Installing the Command Line Tools (expect a GUI popup):
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install
Password:
sudo: /usr/bin/xcode-select: command not found
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install
```

I didnt understand the problem with the xcode
but didt kite get so hope you can help me with this 
before hand every try its appricieted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675993/xcode-select-command-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode. It might be that u need to accept terms and conditions.

Comment: I had open xcode but cannot acces location in the preference menu, it freeze xcode when i try to access it

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Xcode command line tools?

```
 $ xcode-select --install
```

An important dependency before Homebrew can work is the Command Line Tools for Xcode.